# How to add a CSS file to a page's head in the app folder of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In a 'old fashion' way (utilising) */pages* I would edit *_app.js* files under */pages* directory adding something like:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <> 
<Head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
      </Head>
<Component {...pageProps} />
</>
}
```

However, in the new version, Next.js 13, there is no */pages/_app.js* file. There are *layout.js* and *head.js* instead. When I try to add in *head.js* (next to /favicon.ico) import, I get this error:

> react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Cannot render a  outside the main document without knowing its
> precedence. Consider adding precedence="default" or moving it into the
> root  tag.

And when I try to import in *layout.js* file as below:

```
import "/css/styles.css";
```

I am getting compile error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '/css/styles.css'

I was checking the official docs, but they suggest only how to import from global styles (../../..) and not from the public folder.

Comment: I am still looking for some docs about the head.js and can not seem to find any... can you share some with me?

Comment: Ok it seems like it has been depricated ... https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a CSS that gets imported from `public` folder, you can do it in `head.js` as you said, but you need to add `precedence="default"` to your `link`, as they say in the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head):

> If you want to manually place `<link rel="stylesheet" />`, it needs a precedence field which is a new React-specific attribute `<link rel="stylesheet" precedence="default" />`.

```js
// in head.js, alongside layout.js and page.js

export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Create Next App</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
      <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" precedence="default" />
    </>
  );
}
```

You may get an Eslint warning saying *"Do not include stylesheets manually"* that you can deactivate by adding this comment:

```
{/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-css-tags */}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" precedence="default" />
```

Also, as you may already know,  including a css file like this doesn't allow to have live reloading when you change its content, for example. So to be used for external CSS that won't often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ../.. to import from the `public` folder.

With the directory structure

```
/[project root]
  /public
    /css
      - styles.css
  /app
    - layout.js
```

You can import your styles using `import '../public/css/styles.css'`

Comment: Sure, however whole idea with using public is to not have to use  ../.. . Especially if you work on nested components and one day decide to move them - the path will break.